# Combinations Of String While Maintaining Order Of Words

Tags: algorithm, permutation, combinations

Given a string:

```
String words = "Mary had a little lamb";
```

how to obtain a combination of sentence fragments while the order of occurrence of words in the original sentence is maintained ???

example:

```
{'Mary had a little lamb'}
{'Mary had a little', 'lamb'}
{'Mary had a', 'little lamb'}, {'Mary had a', 'little', 'lamb'}
{'Mary had', 'a little lamb'}, {'Mary had', 'a little', 'lamb'}, {'Mary had', 'a', 'little lamb'}, {'Mary had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb'}
{'Mary', 'had a little lamb'}, {'Mary', 'had a little', 'lamb'}, {'Mary', 'had a', 'little lamb'} and so on...
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about it this way:

```
Mary <1> had <2> a <3> little <4> lamb
```

Each of these `<number>`s can be either true or false. If it is true, then you cut the sentence in that location.

So, if you have n+1 words, your problem gets reduced to going through binary representation of numbers with n bit, that is from 0 to 2^n-1

Examples:

```
0110 -> {'Mary had', 'a', 'little lamb'}
1111 -> {'Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb'}
0001 -> {'Mary had a little', 'lamb'}
1011 -> {'Mary', 'had a', 'little', 'lamb'}
```

Comment: Nice :) but my problem has a constraint, in that, if <2> is set to false, i cannot have <3> or <4> or any such following variables to be true. That will not preserve the order. 

Example: Such a combination is not permitted - {'Mary', 'little lamb'}

Comment: Thanks for the example :) helped

Comment: I don't think it would be hard to find the pattern if you think about it in binary numbers, right?

Answer (score 2):

To get the output shown in your question, though not in the same order, this is what I would do.
I will be using *Mathematica* code, but the concepts are universal.

```
string = "Mary had a little lamb";
set = StringSplit[string]
n = Length@set
```

> ```
> {"Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb"}
> 5
> ```

So you will need a function that breaks the sentence into words (StringSplit).

Then you will need a function to generate [integer partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_partitions) and a permutation function that is aware of duplicate elements.  Algorithms for both can be found here on StackOverflow.

```
IntegerPartitions[n]
```

> ```
> {{5}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}
> ```

Once we permute each partition ("for each" is `/@`) we get all ways to linearly split a set of five parts:

```
parts = Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n]
```

> ```
> {{5}, {4, 1}, {1, 4}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1, 1}, {1, 3, 1},
>  {1, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 1},
>  {1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}
> ```

Finally we need a function to split a set according to a sequences of lengths.  I call mine dynamicPartition:

```
dynamicPartition[set, #] & /@ parts // Column
```

> ```
> {{Mary,had,a,little,lamb}}
> {{Mary,had,a,little},{lamb}}
> {{Mary},{had,a,little,lamb}}
> {{Mary,had,a},{little,lamb}}
> {{Mary,had},{a,little,lamb}}
> {{Mary,had,a},{little},{lamb}}
> {{Mary},{had,a,little},{lamb}}
> {{Mary},{had},{a,little,lamb}}
> {{Mary,had},{a,little},{lamb}}
> {{Mary,had},{a},{little,lamb}}
> {{Mary},{had,a},{little,lamb}}
> {{Mary,had},{a},{little},{lamb}}
> {{Mary},{had,a},{little},{lamb}}
> {{Mary},{had},{a,little},{lamb}}
> {{Mary},{had},{a},{little,lamb}}
> {{Mary},{had},{a},{little},{lamb}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 word delimiters (spaces) here. Every space may be replaced (or not) by sentence delimiter. So there are 16 = 2^4 cases, which correspond to binary numbers 0000...1111.